# Network issue while starting Docker container for dotnet core console application

Tags: sql-server, docker, .net-core, connection-string, docker-container

I have created a simple console application in .NET Core with EF Core executing a SQL Server stored procedure from the server that's accessible only through a VPN connection. I was able to run the application on its own, but the container always exists throwing network error when I start it.

URL referred to implement container: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/build-container?tabs=windows

**Context:** the password has special characters as well

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
@"Data Source=###.##.#.##\sql_dev,-#####;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;Enlist=True;User ID=UID;Password=PWD;");
}
```

I identified the IP and port using the following:

```
SELECT
   CONNECTIONPROPERTY('local_net_address') AS local_net_address,
   CONNECTIONPROPERTY('local_tcp_port') AS local_tcp_port
```

**Command executing the procedure:**

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC dbo.spToBExecuted @Param='Value'");
```

I was able to successfully create the container but was not able to start the container, it exits with the following error message:

Please help me solve the issue. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid), also need confirmation if the VPN has anything to do with this.

```
> Unhandled exception. Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)
>
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken, DbConnectionPool pool, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)  
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)  
> at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)  
> at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)  
> at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)  
> at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)  
> at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)  
> at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
    at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
    at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.ExecuteSqlCommand(DatabaseFacade databaseFacade, RawSqlString sql, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.ExecuteSqlCommand(DatabaseFacade databaseFacade, RawSqlString sql, Object[] parameters)
    at NetCore.Docker.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\UName\Documents\projects\App\Program.cs:line 16
    
> ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

Please help me solve the issue: `(provider: TCP Provider, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)`,
Also need confirmation if the VPN has anything to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a [verbatim string literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#regular-and-verbatim-string-literals) for your connection string so you don't need to escape your backslash characters.

Try using the following instead (note the single backslash):

```cs
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
@"Data Source=###.##.#.##\sql_dev,-#####;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;Enlist=True;User ID=UID;Password=PWD;");
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I tried this and still facing the same issue. I missed to edit the post.

Comment: @RandomUser Is there actually a `-` character in your port number `Data Source=###.##.#.##\sql_dev,-#####;`? I don't think the connection string parser would like negative numbers.

Comment: @RandomUser Also your question's most recent edit changed `User ID=UID;` to `Usqer ID=UID;` with a `q`.

Comment: as you pointed out, the post has Usqer instead of User, but the solution has the correct spelling. About the port, I ran the `CONNECTIONPROPERTY('local_tcp_port')` command to find it out.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to successfully start the container after switching to Windows container.

**URL Referred:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/set-up-environment?tabs=Windows-10-Client